# Running Unix commands from Oracle apex application

Tags: oracle, unix, oracle-apex

Is it possible to run commands on another Unix server from an Oracle apex application ?
Oracle apex and Unix are on different machines .

Comment: If you deploy an API Rest into UNIX server, you can reach it calling the endpoints created. But you'll need appropriate permissions on UNIX. Don't forget to create an ACL (Access Control List) in your database.

Answer (score 2):

Apex is just a layer on top of the database.

- From within the oracle database you can execute OS commands, so you could execute a script that connects from your database server over ssh.
- or you could wrap your unix command in a cgi script and have it run of http. In pl/sql you could then invoke it via apex_web_service.make_rest_request

Make sure you check security

Answer (score 0):

No you cannot. If your requirement is just to transfer the files, you can use ftp or sftp commands. But to perform unix operations, you cannot run in different machines